# What exactly changes when range of motion improves through stretching?

Tags: exercise, stretching, range-of-motion

Imagine I haven't moved much in recent years (couch potato, or injury...) Assume no other problems.

Then I do exercise/stretching/physical therapy for a few months, and my range of motion in, say, the hips, (or some other joint) increases.

If a surgeon (with a microscope if needed) were to look inside me before and after, and compare, what would they see that is different?

Comment: Based on personal experience and guesswork, I would say that one of the things that changes is the coefficients in the cerebellum.